# Laravel 5.4 : 404 Page return FatalErrorException instead of NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel-5.4

Just found wired problem when try to catch 404 page not found
but Laravel return `fatal error` with this

`(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' not found
in RouteCollection.php (line 179)`

but in other project return

`NotFoundHttpException ▼
  -statusCode: 404
  -headers: []`

im not sure what's going on after i update composer
what i try

1. make /resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
2. edit /App/Exceptions/Handler.php

had no luck, I will appreciate your help

**PS.** i was found related issue here

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21663

Answer (score 0):

After check vendor folder it's missing `exception` folder inside `vendor/symfony/http-kernel`. i think it's an internet problem when install composer or update it. so i just copy folder there then it's back to work